# Synchronising data between MySQL and SQL Server over an unreliable network connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

This question relates to implementing redundancy when having two databases syncronising on 2 different servers. First of all, I'll explain the setup so that you can understand the backround of the issue.

I have two different servers, operating different operating systems with different DB types at 2 different locations.

```
Server 1 (local server):
Windows 2003 Small Business Server OS
MSSQL DB Server
Server-Side Language - C# ASP.NET

Server 2 (website server):
Linux CentOS 6
MySQL DB
Server-Side Language - PHP
```

Server 1 runs the internal management side of the software and server 2 is the external website interface (server 2 has some management aspects 2). Unfortunately, we have seen frequent loss of broadband at our office and this means that communciation between the two servers may not always be possible (we have 3G broadband redundancy but it takes time for Dynamic DNS to update the DNS record with our new IP address when we lose the primary broadband). This is what caused the need for each server to have its own DB - as we can't allow one or the other of these two sides to go offline entirely.

As such, I've built it into both servers such that both have their own local database but apply any changes to other server as well. If the other server cannot be connected to, it will save the query to the local DB so that the queries can be applied when the other server becomes available again. This leaves two issues:

1. A general point about syncing between databases like this - how
   can I best avoid conflicting queries being applied when the servers
   reconnect? See example 1 below for a description of what I mean. This
   problem is minimised because the connection should only be lost for a
   couple minutes - until the DNS record is updated.
2. When applying the back-logged queries, I would like to have the script automatically apply the queries (rather than having to manually launch a script to resolve back-logged queries). However, I'm unsure what effect this would have if the user navigated away from the page whilst it was still appying the back-logged queries in the background.

Example 1:

If a user on the website side (server 2) changes their email address, or phone number etc., and a user on the management side (sever 1) changes that user's details then these two queries will have conflicting information. When the servers reconnect then the two queries will be applied to the other server - and the entries will still be out of sync.

P.S. Sorry the question is so long.

Comment: Is there a problem with my question? Is it in the wrong place? It has 4 votes to close it and no-one has told my why.

Comment: A vote to move a question in SO appears as a close vote, so it's likely that 4 people have voted to move this to the DBA site (I did).

Comment: @Pondlife thanks, I hummed and hawed about where to post it. I guess I got it wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-invent database replication. Use the one provided by your database software instead.

However, this means you should switch to the same RDBMS on both ends. MySQL replication is fairly reliable on WAN connections and will work reliably between platforms and versions.

Comment: So your advice would be to switch the DB on one of the servers, and, as a result, probably the OS too (I don't much fancy running MS SQL server on a linux platform)? Because that's a pretty serious ask. Your point is very valid for anyone else that comes across this question but I'm a little restricted due to historical reasons.

Comment: You can run MySQL on Windows Server. Master-master is quite hard, so I suggest to use *one* instance for writing, the other for read-only access. In case of a disaster or total system failure of the master, you can promote the read-only slave to become a new master. It's not trivial to build what you have in mind as software can't solve versioning conflicts as you explain in your 'Example 1'.

Comment: A Master-Slave relationship between the servers would be great whilst they were connected and would at least allow basic functionality to continue when the connection was lost. As I only expect to lose connection for a few minutes at most this is certainly a good option. My main concern is that the management side needs to maintain write access since it handles alot of the day-to-day company management. However, that means that I would be unable to keep track of document downloads etc. on the website server whilst the connection is down.

Comment: @PeterScott You can't solve it reliably. This is a basic proven law in distributed systems. If two systems overwrite the same data (row) independently, then there's no way to merge this automatically other than sacrificing one of the transactions. If that's what you want, you're asking for trouble: data drift and user confusion. "I really changed X, Y, Z in the system, but some other value appeared somehow!" The prevention of 3-minute outage of a system isn't worth it. really.

Comment: You're right. I'll switch over to MySQL and have Server 2 run a read-only version of server 1's DB. The download information that I'm worried about losing is only able to be written by the website server (since that's where docs are distributed) so I may create 2 DBs on each server and have the new DB store info that only server 2 is able to write. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gertvdijk, the best solution would be to use the same RDBMS on both servers (though I'd go with MySQL over MSSQL since it will run just fine on both host OSes) and then use the replication software for that RDBMS.

However if you're unwilling or unable to do that the next best alternative I can think of in your case would be to create a "transaction log" on both servers. At it's simplest something that captures a UTC date/time and an SQL command to be executed:

```
2012-12-14 13:42:13 UPDATE users SET email = 'me2@mydomain.com' WHERE id = 13542
2012-12-14 13:43:55 UPDATE ....
...
```

Obviously you would want to use parameterized queries instead of what I've shown - it's just easier for me to explain my idea without getting mired down in implementation details.

So each server is keeping a log of it's transactions and suddenly you lose your office connection.  A few minutes later when it comes up both servers exchange their transaction logs and merge them with their own transaction log, sorting all records by the UTC date/time stamp.  Now you can execute all the queries that happened on both servers and not worry about them being out of sync, even if changes were made to the exact same column while the connection between servers was lost. If you're worried about the exact same column being changed at the exact same time you can put the microtime in the date/time stamps.

Comment: I had planned to save dateTime stamps with the queries when I logged but it hadn't ocurred to me to merge the two lists. There are certainly some potential dfficulties to be sorted (based around the fact that queries are saved locally at the time they are generated) but I think they can be fixed. Would you recommend gertvdijk's suggestion first because it's easier to implement or do you think it is a more robust solution?

Comment: Lot of hand-waving here, and ultimately it doesn't really work.  You say to [*merge both transaction logs, sort by UTC, then execute all transactions on both servers*].  Problems: 1) UTC sinking in microtime is impossible, 2) this does not preserve transactional integrity, 3) each server has ***already*** executed half of these transactions, so executing them again will cause logical corruption, ... etc., etc.  In essence, this doesn't solve the race condition problem, it just systematically ignores it.

Comment: I didn't say anything about SYNCING in microtime, I said to take a time stamp that includes microtime - which can be sorted later when preparing to execute missed transactions.

Comment: @PeterScott - I recommend gertvdijk's solution because that's really the best way to handle this kind of problem. There would be some work involved in porting all the data from one RDBMS to another but after that it should be much easier, and more robust, to use replication tools that are tried and true.